# Iterating through dictionary, 5 rows at a time

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to open a csv file with csv.DictReader, read in just the first 5 rows of data, perform the primary process of my script, then read in the next 5 rows and do the same for them.  Rinse and repeat.

I believe I have a method that works, however I am having issues with the last lines of the data not processing.  I know I need to modify my if statement so that it also checks for if I'm at the end of the file, but am having trouble finding a way to do that.  I've found methods online, but they involve reading in the whole file to get a row count but doing so would defeat the purpose of this script as I'm dealing with memory issues.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import csv
count = 0
data = []
with open('test.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    
    for row in reader:
        count +=1
        data.append(row)

        if count % 5 == 0 or #something to check for the end of the file:
            #do stuff
            data = []
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you use `for row in reader:`, then there should be no need to check if you've reached end of file. Do you have a specific reason to perform this check?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `chunksize` argument when reading in the csv. This will step by step read in the number of lines:

```
import pandas as pd
reader = pd.read_csv('test.csv', chunksize=5)
for df in reader:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the remaining lines after the `for` loop body. You can also use the more pythonic `enumerate`.

```
import csv

data = []
with open('test.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for count, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        data.append(row)
        if count % 5 == 0:
            # do stuff
            data = []

    print('handling remaining lines at end of file')
    print(data)
```

considering the file

```
a,b
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,6
7,7
```

outputs

```
handling remaining lines at end of file
[OrderedDict([('a', '6'), ('b', '6')]), OrderedDict([('a', '7'), ('b', '7')])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using the iterator

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    
    value = True
    while value:
        data = []
        for _ in range(5):             # Get 5 rows
            value = next(reader, False) 
            if value:
                data.append(value)
        print(data)   #List of 5 elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Staying along the lines of what you wrote and not including any other imports:

```
import csv
data = []
with open('test.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)
        if len(data) > 5:
            del data[0]
        if len(data) == 5:
            # Do something with the 5 elements
            print(data)
```

The if statements allow the array to be loaded with 5 elements before processing on the begins.

```
class ZeroIterNumberException(Exception):
    pass
class IterN:
    def __init__(self, iterator, n):
        if n<1:
            raise ZeroIterNumberException("{} is not a valid number of rows.".format(n))
        self.iterator = iterator
        self.n = n
        self.cache = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.cache.append(next(self.iterator))
        if len(self.cache) < self.n:
            return self.__next__()
        if len(self.cache) > self.n:
            del self.cache[0]
        if len(self.cache) == 5:
            return self.cache
```

Comment: This produces a "rolling window" over the file, not what OP wants to achieve